# How can I add some line numbers of emacs into pdf created by latex

Tags: emacs, line-numbering

Is it possible to print Line Number in emacs to the Latex pdf for lines that I prefer?

If it is easy, I want to use those numbers with M-g M-g (goto-line command)

I asked the same question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62805/how-can-i-add-some-line-numbers-of-emacs-into-pdf-created-by-latex), I am not sure which one is correct.

Edit: To make the question more clear, lets say

```
L56: Some text....
L57: Some text....
L58: \printLineNumberOfEmacsIntoPDF
L59: \begin{equation}
L60:     Some Equation
L61: \end{equation}
```

I am looking for a command like this such that it will print 'Line 58' into the pdf created by Latex.

Comment: Please clarify the use case, or cases, you have in mind. E.g., are you looking to typeset a code block "as is" or "verbatim", with a monospaced font and indentations exactly as they occur in the input file? If so, have you looked into the [fancyvrb](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb) package, which lets you achieve these objectives in a straightforward fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are searching for the primitive `\inputlineno`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\printLineNumberOfEmacsIntoPDF{Line \the\inputlineno}
\begin{document}
\printLineNumberOfEmacsIntoPDF
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `fancyvrb` package lets you print line numbers along with verbatim material, and it lets you customize how the line numbers are formatted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % for 'Verbatim' environment
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{{\scriptsize Line \arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
Some text ...
Some text ...
\printLineNumberOfEmacsIntoPDF
\begin{equation}
     1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the first line number is supposed to be different from `1`, simply add a `firstnumber=<DesiredNumber>` option, i.e., change

```
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
```

to

```
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,firstnumber=55]
```